# Kotlin BigDecimal range with custom step

Tags: java, kotlin, count, range, bigdecimal

I have a string "1;5;0.5" it means BigDecimal range 1..5 with step 0.5. So, i have to convert it into a kotlin range, and count elements. do something like this:

```
val str = "1;5;0.5"
var (from, to, st) = str.split(";").map { it.toBigDecimal() }
val numbersWithStep = (from..to step st).count()
```

But it doesn't work. It works only with int numbers. There is any more simple way to count elements instead of using while cycle?

Comment: you can implement your own BigDecimal progression, see here a [kotlinlang discussion](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-bigdecimal-progression/3654)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean, like a really simple math?

```
(to - from) / st + 1
```

Just note that division has to be done with rounding down. A working example for BigDecimals would be:

```
(to - from).divideToIntegralValue(st) + BigDecimal.ONE
```

You may need to check for `to < from` if this is your case.